# Is there a way to select an object which has the same name as a string

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure this is possible, but, is there a way to select an object which has the same name as a string, and use it in a .each loop?

```
    var test = "myobj"; 

    var myobj = {"1" : "2", "2" : "3"};

    function testing(test){

         // If i do a console.log on the variale "test":
         console.log(test); // will show the string: "myobj"

         typeof(test); // is string

         // somehow select the object with the name myobj, and maybe iterate through it?
         jQuery.each(myobj, function(key, val){
            alert(val); // right now this will alert the actual letters: m y o b j
         });

    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `window[myobj]` ?

Comment: It worked using window["myobj"] - could you please answer this question, and maybe explain why? Ty.. is this crossbrowser?

Comment: See Sebastian's explanation, you can mark his answer as accepted if this is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address object properties with their string name like this:

```
obj["property"]
```

In your example you created `test` as global, which is a property of `window` (I assume you are testing this in the browser):

```
window[myobj]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are global

```
  var test = "myobj";
  var myobj = {"1" : "2", "2" : "3"};

  console.log(window[test]);
```

Keep in mind that if you put your code inside a `$(function() { ... }); wrapper that`var test`and`var myobj`will not be global and therefore not available under the`window` object.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers pointed out, in your example you can use `window[test]` *if* your `myObj` variable is global.

However, that is not the way you should do this. Presumably you will have a number of other related variables like `myobj2`, `yetAnotherObj`, etc. Otherwise there wouldn't be much point in doing this. But you don't want to clutter up your global namespace with these variables.

Instead, create an object which contains all of your other variables:

```
var myObjects = {
    myobj: {"1" : "2", "2" : "3"},
    myobj2: {"4" : "5", "6" : "7"},
    yetAnotherObj: {"8" : "9", "10" : "11"}
};
```

and now, given your `test` variable with the name of one of these objects in it, you would use:

```
myObjects[test]
```

Not only does this avoid cluttering the global namespace, but it will also work even if `myObjects` and the objects contained within it are local variables instead of global.